# Why does changing redrawing this circuit in the new way work?

Tags: homework-and-exercises, electric-circuits, electrical-resistance, batteries

I was doing a circuits question and the mark scheme showed they had redrawn the circuit in a new way but I didn’t understand why part of the old circuit was equivalent to the new one.

[image]

I understand how they went from the 2 20ohm resistors in parallel to the single 10ohm (at the top left). But I don’t understand how they could redraw, as they did, the part I’ve circled in red. I understand that extending wires and bending them should make no difference to how a circuit works (because the wires are ideal so they have no resistance) but it seems to me that they’ve added some connections and removed others and which means that the current in the bottom circuit cannot flow in the same way that it flows in the top one.
*Here’s an example to show what I mean:*
In the new circuit, current can flow in all 4 ways simultaneously (from the 10ohm resistor on the left to the top 24ohm resistor on the right; from the
10ohm on the left to the 24ohm on the bottom right; from the 40 on the left to the 24 on the top right and from the 40 on the left to the 24 on the bottom right). BUT in the old circuit, it can only flow in 3 out of 4 of these ways (so let’s imagine the current in the middle vertical connection to the 4ohm flows upwards. So this means the current can flow from the 40 to the top 24 or the bottom 24 or from the top 10 to the top 24 but the current CANT flow from the top 10 to the bottom 24 because current would have to flow DOWN the vertical middle connection! If the current in the middle vertical connection flowed upwards it could still only flow in 3 out of the 4 ways in the new setup).
The same principle applies if current were flowing from right to left instead of left to right.
So how can the new and old setups be equivalent in resistance if current in the old setup can flow in fewer ways that it can flow through the new one?

Comment: Look at the red circled part  in the bottom circuit, and in your imagination slowly move the two small vertical wires closer and closer together.

Comment: You’ve actually proved why this heuristic of counting current paths (but sometimes ruling some of them out) isn’t valid or useful. We conclude that Nature doesn’t conserve the current path quantity.

Comment: Thank you everyone, makes much more sense now when I've heard a lot of different ways of explaining it. And @Chemomechanics, it's a good point about how "nature doesn't conserve current path quantity" - I think that's what I was most confused about.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

All comments and answers really helped me get my head around this. But I think Chemomechanics comment about how "nature doesn't conserve current path quanity" made the most sense - (although I can't accept the comment as answer hence why I wrote this one).

Answer (score 3):

All "wires" are assumed to have zero resistance. For that reason the "wire" connected between the pairs of resistors in the first diagram can be shrunk to  (replaced by) a point in the second diagram.

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 1):

The change in the diagrams, in my opinion, are only changes between a series and parallel circuit orientation (it is also labeled on the two diagrams). Essentially, what they did is group the resistors and make all flow in the middle convene at a single intersection. That doesn't change the way electricity would flow from the resistors in any way.

By that same token and to answer the logical paradox you proposed: We know that the electricity in this diagram is flowing from left to right. If you look closely at how electricity flows in the two diagrams you can see that, in both diagrams, it would be logical for 10 to flow to either of the 24s, as the electricity would still be flowing rightwards.

Also, I think the assumption that the vertical middle connection flows upwards if when you look at the electricity flow in the standard way, which is when the ultimate flow of all electricity goes from the + pole to the - pole. However, regardless, looking at it the "correct" way, the argument still stands.

Hope this helps!